# How to make a gallery of images to appear when you click on text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am redesigning a furniture website. On one particular page I am going to have my 'stock' catalogue. What I want to happen is a list of furniture categories to feature on the page e.g.

```
<li> Beds </li> 
<li> Sofas </li> 
<li> Chairs </li> 
<!-- more options... -->
```

When you click on say the word `Beds`, a gallery of images of beds expands on the screen. I then want to be able to 'hide' this gallery if say the customer wanted next to look at the `Sofas` gallery.

It doesn't have to be anything to fancy, just a simple basic structure. Hope this makes sense. Really appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: There are many many gallery popup plugins available... do some web surfing, pick one you like that has good documentation

Comment: if you are updating a website, then they probably are already using something that you can use.  Joomla comes to mind, jquery ui might be it too.  Figure out what ui library they are already using and look up gallery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.beds').on("click", function(){

  //show respective gallery
  alert('show beds gallery')

});

$('.sofas').on("click", function(){
     //show respective gallery
  alert('show sofas gallery')

});

$('.chairs').on("click", function(){
    //show respective gallery
  alert('show chairs gallery')
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="furnitures">
  <li class="beds">Beds</li>
  <li class="sofas">Sofas</li>
  <li class="chairs">Chairs</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this is great thank you, so how and where do I put the gallery of images?

Comment: wherever you want you can put the gallery of images its just you have to show and hide in respective list items' click.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand.. I literally need the answer in laymans terms

Comment: Please share your code of which gallery plugin you are using

Answer (score 0):

Compressed way of vinayakj which works with any number of list items.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="furnitures">
  <li rel="beds">Beds</li>
  <li rel="sofas">Sofas</li>
  <li rel="chairs">Chairs</li>
</ul>
<div id="gallery-beds" class="gallery">Beds gallery</div>
<div id="gallery-sofas" class="gallery">Sofas gallery</div>
<div id="gallery-chairs" class="gallery">Chairs gallery</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.gallery {
  display: none;
}
```

** JS **

```
$().ready(function() {
    $('#furnitures li[rel]').click(function() {
        $('.gallery').hide();
        $('#gallery-'+$(this).attr('rel')).show();
    });
});
```

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8L3r8ro/).